# Opening Reminder application within iOS application?

Tags: ios, ios7

Is it possible to use iOS Reminder Built in Application within the App I develop?
I dont want to use OPEN URL concept, because it will quit my app an open Reminder App?
Can I please any Custom Reminder App deveoped by iOS SDk , which will create Reminder
in iOS's Reminder Application

Comment: You can use UILocalNotification to set reminder.

Answer (score 1):

There is a reminders API that allows you to create and retrieve reminders.

You'll first have to ask for user permission to do so:

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] initWithAccessToEntityTypes:EKEntityMaskReminder];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) {
        [self createReminder:store];
    }
    else {
        // :(
    }
}];
```

To create a reminder you could:

```
- (void)createReminder:(EKEventStore *)store {
    //Create a reminder instance
    EKReminder *aReminder = [EKReminder reminderWithEventStore:store];

    // Set the properties
    aReminder.title = @"Remember to do X";
    ...

    // Then save the reminder to the store
    NSError *error = nil;
    [store saveReminder:aReminder commit:YES error:&error];

    // Be responsible
    if (error) {
        [self rememberToHandleYourErrors:error];
    }
}
```